# Get a SessionFactory from LocalSessionFactoryBean without HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE and 4.0.1.Final and read that I must avoid the use of HibernateTemplate. I didn't found a complete example in the web, so I wrote this code, but doesn't work.

Dao class

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```

Spring Config

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        ...
    </bean>
```

But an exception is thrown : I think it's normal because sessionFactory it's not a LocalSessionFactoryBean, but i don't know how to fix it.

```
Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.test.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.


The complete stacktrace : <br />
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.test.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.test.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        ... 32 more
` <br />
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work, because the bean is a FactoryBean<SessionFactory>, and will thus provide a SessionFactory to autowire. Show us the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, unable to make injection work.

My problem was "sequence". Hibernate xml must be invoked first.

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<!-- init hibernate first -->
<import resource="classpath:HibernateContext.xml"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy" />
```